# Can a Dart Project be exported as HTML,JS/CSS?

Tags: cordova, dart

Am new to dart and am beginning to like it. I am doing some offline html5 code and am thinking how to export the project as htmls/css and js?

Was thinking I maybe able to use it in PhoneGap. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *export* you can use [pub build](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-build.html) if you follow the [Pub Package Layout Conventions](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html). Otherwise you have to directly use [dart2js](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dart2js/).

Yes you can use Dart to build a mobile webapp with PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with 'export'.
A Dart project consists itself of HTML,CSS and Dart no need to export anything.

When you 'build' a Dart project Dart is transpiled (compiled) to JavaScript. The result is a directory containing HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

When you want to use a PhoneGap/Cordova application you have to make the Dart project structure accordingly. The build result is then a valid Cordova application.

For a start you can look at http://docs.rikulo.org/ui/latest/Getting_Started/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to generate the java-script files from your dart files, just do.
pub build --mode=release --all